# Importing SugarCRM Accounts and Contacts into mysql for Joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, sugarcrm

I know Joomla website development fairly well, but SugarCRM practically not at all.  I had my friend using hosted SugarCRM Professional, manually export selected fields from her 300 accounts to an excel spreadsheet and selected fields from her 900 contacts to another excel spreadsheet.  Using phpmyadmin I imported the excel spreadsheets into my Joomla mysql database. I then wrote some modules to display the accounts and contacts on her Joomla website.

My question is, I'd like to make it so she can refresh the the Joomla website from the Sugar whenever she wants, with some simple steps.  Can Sugar Professional export to a mysql bypassing the ExceL?  Can hosted Sugar Professional export to the community version of SugarCRM - because I could host that with my Joomla and probably go right into the tables - the only thing is I don't want to copy financial related data fields from her Professional Sugar tables.   What technologies would a professional SugarCRM Developer use?

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions out there that may already do this for you. Check out https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/sugarycb for one of them. Could save a ton of time/hassle.